# Possible to calculate how much data been loaded with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been busy with some AJAX code. I want to calculate how much data has been loaded and I want to display it with percents.

All my preloaded info is inside "feedback".
Can I calculate how much DATA it contains (in bytes) and can I also view the progress? Like when it has loaded: 10kb, 20kb, 30kb etc

My code:

```
function calc(page)
    {
    $('#pageLoad h2').animate({ marginTop : '0px'}, 200);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:            './pages/page.php',
            type:           'POST',
            data:           'page='+page,
            success:        function( feedback )
            {
                $('#content').html( feedback );
            }                               

        });
    };
```

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: First of all you should fix the syntax errors in the code and use `data: {page: page}` insetead of `data: 'page='+page`

Comment: @ThiefMaster the latter is perfectly valid syntax (but in the question it should not have the additional `+'`

Comment: Lawl, my bad. I used to have 2 post values, but i removed one.

Comment: @tandu: It is, but I **highly** doubt he's escaping characters like `&` in that string. So better let jQuery do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *is* possible. XHRs have a [`progress` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress). The only problem is accessing the XHR object - unfortunately `beforeSend` only receives the `jqXHR` object and not the underlying XHR object. It is also not accessible as a property of the wrapper. You can however hook into the creation process of the XHR object by adding the following option to `$.ajax()`:

```
xhr: function () {
    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr(); // call the original function
    xhr.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total;
            // Do something with download progress
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
}
```

---

Here's my initial solution. It is extremely hard to combine with jQuery since you can't easily hook into the onreadystatechange handler and cannot safely replace it after it has been set:

<strike>You need to add a custom `onreadystatechange` handler. When the `readyState` of the XHR object becomes `2` (*HEADERS_RECEIVED*) you can access the `Content-Length` header to get the total size and then wait for the event to fire with `xhr.readyState == 3` (*LOADING*).</strike>

Then you can calculate the progress by looking at `xhr.responseText.length`.
However, this will only fire once. So you need to start a timer (using `setInterval()`) which will check the ready state and response size e.g. every 100 msecs. As soon as the request finishes you stop the interval again using `clearInterval()`.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, this is the way to go, there's some more on this [here](http://dave-bond.com/quick-tips/jquery-ajax-progress-html5/) wih code examples etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to those events. Much cleaner than using a timer.

Comment: Yeah, I did'nt actually see that your answer was'nt about the progress event, but intervals, until after I had commented. I just noticed your comments on an old question regarding the older jQ versions etc. and figured you had probably found the progress event as well, and after I posted I figured you'd have a look at it and update your answer anyway, so all's well that ends well i suppose.