# Is there a way to check how much of the picture has been loaded, in pixels, from the top?

Tags: javascript

The heading sums is all. Though, the case is where I have a long (20x2000px) picture as a sprite for thumbnails. It would be nice if I could start showing the sprite only for the thumbnails that already have required-part of the sprite loaded, and show loader in the meantime.

All I need is to know how much of the picture has been loaded in pixels from the top (supposing that it is not progressive). I thought of using file size to estimate that, though that would be very inaccurate.

The main question everyone is having - *why to do this at all?*

There is a page that displays somewhat 100 thumbnails. It would be a nice thing if this page had a sprite of those thumbnails generated in the descending thumbnail order.

[image]

Such page already exists. The screenshot is attached. User can see a gray placeholder while the sprite is being loaded. I want to display the thumbnail only when the required part of the sprite for that thumbnail is already loaded.

> @Guy Sounds like a theoretical question then... Per your comment on the answer below, if you're loading 10MB 'sprites' you're doing it wrong.

No, there is nothing wrong about it if this can be achieved. That would reduce the number of calls by 100 every time the page is being called. That is a remarkable speed improvement even if everything is cached.

Comment: Question: Why?? Maybe we could offer a better solution if we knew the goal...

Comment: Since that's not a very big image.. couldn't you just wait for the whole file?  Seems like a lot of extra processing for little perceived value.

Comment: @Fosco, the size is theoretical. Practically it can be anything.

Comment: @Guy Sounds like a theoretical question then...  Per your comment on the answer below, if you're loading 10MB 'sprites' you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're trying to do, but in short, you can't. Counting pixels in JavaScript, if it possible at all (maybe with canvas? I don't think so though) would just be unreasonably resource-consuming. Loading all the images separately (i.e., not as one sprite), however, will give you exactly the effect you're looking for as a default on most browsers, albeit at the cost of more requests.

The solution? Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN), so the browser can fetch all 100 images at the same time, without necessarily putting the strain on your own server.

Comment: That's not the solution. That's the most straightforward workaround, completely missing the point of why I want to do this in the first place – optimisation.

Comment: If a workaround solves the original problem, how is it not a solution?

Comment: That's like if someone asks you – `I need to get from point A to point B, 100 miles apart, in 10 minutes`, and you answer – `run`. It is solution to only part of the question.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid comparison, as in this case, a CDN does in fact allow you to go from A to B in 10 minutes, so to speak. It will load the images progressively, as you asked, and in a very browser-compatible and degradable manner, without relying on JavaScript trickery. The only overhead will be the extra HTTP headers, which will add an extra 1% to your bandwidth (assuming an image is 100kB and HTTP headers 1kB). If your only goal is to reduce the size, and not the speed, then I admit other solutions are more apt.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

After some additional searching, I found what looks to be a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559264/possible-to-calculate-how-much-data-been-loaded-with-ajax) and is similar to a solution provided [here](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/474909-how-check-progress-xmlhttprequest).  The basic idea is to make an AJAX request and monitor the progress.

---

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to avoid that brief period of time that a page is loading (or after a even occurs) where images haven't finished transferring and don't yet appear where they should.

The problem I think you're going to run into (if this is a scenario where the page is loading) is that you're waiting for your placeholder image and the sprite to come across the wire.  By the time your placeholder gets over, your sprite may have gotten there already or be milliseconds behind, and you haven't avoided the situation described above.

If you're dealing with a mouseover event or something similar where the sprite is requested for the first time, you can pre-load the sprite image by calling it via JavaScript when the page loads, so it'll already be cached and ready when the event fires.

Comment: I know how to preload image. The question doesn't for that. Supposedly, if the sprite is 10mb, that will keep the user waiting for quiet a while. Therefore, I am looking to check if there is a way to see how much of the sprite has been loaded and start showing the thumbnails that are ready.

Comment: I am not aware of a way, but wanted to provide some alternative info that may be helpful.  I don't know what you do or don't know, so figured it'd be best to provide more information than less :)  Another option would be to set the placeholder as the default image and wait for the page to finish loading.  Then swap the sprite in at that time and you have kept a good user experience. -- Also, could you provide a link to the website you took a screenshot of above?

Comment: The website is still not public and not going to be for several weeks. Your suggested alternative approach is worst than as it is, as it requires user to wait for the thumbnail to ully load before seing anything of interest.

Comment: My suggested alternative approach was based on the little information I had to go on and assumptions of how you were using sprites based on the most common ways of using sprites.  This is a bit of a unique case, as the sprite appears to be providing almost the entire visual portion of the page to the user.  I'm curious myself, so I'll do a little digging to see if there is a solution to your question.

Answer (score -2):

I already have a theoretical solution. Before I start working on it, it would be nice if anyone can tell me if there is any major fault in my thinking.

The image is generated server-side, screenshot after screenshot. Therefore, after every screenshot merged into the sprite I can save the thumbnail size information to the database along with the corresponding entry.

Once user lands on the page, I will keep checking how many bytes of the sprite are loaded, loop through every entry that is pending to be displayed, check if the value is greater or equal to the entry "weight" and display or continue the loop appropriately.

Comment: How do you intend to show the image once it is loaded? CSS `background-image` property with offset? Are you aware that browsers don't show background images until they are fully loaded? So your page will just be blank until the full image has loaded, anyway. Or do you intend on using some other mechanism that you're not mentioning?

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, you could maybe use an `<img>` tag with some clever `padding`, `width` and `overflow: hidden` properties. But that would be quite a hack.

Comment: `Are you aware that browsers don't show background images until they are fully loaded?` That's not true. It depends on the browser and image format.

Comment: Of course it depends on the browser. Maybe some browsers don't wait until the full image is there before they show it, but I'm pretty sure most do, and you'll basically be causing those users to stare at a blank page for a very long time. Look, if you're going to ignore any and all advice, don't ask the question in the first place. Or if you don't care about usability and browser-compatibility, only about optimization, then state that it is a theoretical question. If that's the case, my advice would be different.

Comment: @HermanSchaaf `but I'm pretty sure most do`, mind providing any reference? I've tested all browsers that I care about (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, not IE) and all seem to load the image as expected – gradually from top to bottom.

Comment: Here's a test page I set up: http://jsbin.com/eweben/6/edit#preview
I tested on Chrome and Firefox, and you're right, it looks like newer versions of Chrome does load background images progressively. My version of Firefox, however, does not - you stare at a blue screen for a number of seconds before the image suddenly appears. Chrome, too, seems to do quite a bit of extra loading before it finally starts to render (and the draws from top to bottom quickly). I couldn't find any formal reference, only some SO questions that ask whether it can be loaded progressively, with the answer being "no".

Comment: First of all, this is `jpeg`; I didn't even know that jpeg supports progressive loading. My guess is that you'd get broader browser support using PNG.

Comment: Yes, support for PNG might be better (but then you're serving images that are much larger, sort of defeating the purpose of optimization) Just one last suggestion that's not quite what you asked originally, but might solve the same problem: what if you generate a progressive JPEG on the server-side? Then it's one image, and at least some blurry blocks will be shown on the client-side while it's still loading.

Comment: Using anything else than a PNG for a screenshot wouldn't make sense too. The size difference is less than 10% in this case. My purpose is to optimise not the size of the response or use of resources on my server, but to create an effect of blitz loading. Yes, ironically it can be that response is going be bigger.