# JQuery Ajax Request with Percentage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to get the % completion for ajax request.

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        xhr : function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                    //Do something with upload progress here
                }
            }, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                    //Do something with download progress
                    console.log(percentComplete);       
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },
        url : my_path
    }).done(function(data) {

        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The problem is how do I check whether the above code is working or not. I always get `100` in the firebug console, I doubt instead of `100` there should be multiple `%` entries in console.

`my_path` is a PHP page that returns records from MySQL DB. Is there any way to slow down the process/page rendering to check the functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690740/how-to-show-loading-status-in-percentage-for-ajax-response

Comment: @Manibharathi I have already implemented that functionality and need to check the % functionality by slowing down the page rendering or db operation?

Comment: did you use that in local system?

Comment: Percentage of what? Think of it on a pure theoretical level. How is the browser supposed to know how large the request is if it hasn't finished receiving it yet? If you have the server announcing the size via a `Content-Length` header that's one thing, but in the case where you're streaming back results (which is what php typically does I believe) that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - When Uploading, the browser is aware of the file-size.  When Downloading, you must set it in the Header information, which is more than possible in PHP (see my answer, below).

Comment: Wait is he trying to measure upload progress? I totally didn't get that. OP can you please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using DB reads is the size needs to be known first, so you really need a file to test this.

For Downloading (client downloading off from the server), you need to introduce delay, otherwise you're only recourse is to download a huge file.

Try [this script](http://pastebin.com/0yt09QL6), which sets up the correct content length headers and only outputs 50 bytes at a time, with a 1 second delay (you can test it with a relatively small file, woot).

As for Uploading (posting to the server), your only option in this regard is to make it a big file, and discard it when done.