# Is there any callback which i can use after ajax send but before success return for polling purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any callback which i can use after AJAX request send but before success return? lets say my success is taking longer because i am running something in loop but on every iteration i am updating a table for lets say percentage completion. I wanted to poll that table in between and that's the reason i am looking for that callback. any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show loading status in percentage for ajax response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690740/how-to-show-loading-status-in-percentage-for-ajax-response)

Answer (score -1):

As `$.ajax` (or `$.get` or `$.post`) does not block the execution of the script, you could write your polling code right after the ajax call:

```
$.ajax( ... your ajax call ...);
// your polling code
```

Or you could use the `beforeSend` event, that will be executed right before sending the request:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend : function() {
        // your polling code
    }
});
```