# Jquery AJAX submit size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a Javascript canvas and I have drawn on it.

After I finished the drawing I click "Save" and an ajax post is sent to the server with the canvas being converted to base64 image.

The image size can be large and I want to display the percentage of upload being done.
I can clearly see the POST body size on the firebug post dialog. How can I ask the php about how much post size I have received so far, so I can calculate the percentage? 
My code so far is:

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        imgData:canvas.toDataURL()
    },
    url: "/saveImg",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Upload done';)
    },
});
```

And my PHP side is

```
$fName= uniqid();
$UPLOAD_DIR= 'custom/';
$img = $_POST['imgData'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $UPLOAD_DIR .$fName . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

**EDIT**

It looks like using
 `xhr: function()
    {
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      //Upload progress
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        console.log(evt);
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = parseInt((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
        console.log("Upload: " + percentComplete + "% complete")
       }
     }, false);
     return xhr;
   },`
Kinda works, the result is a 2% and 99% instantly, then a 2 minute pause and then a 100%... 
After some experimentation it really matters what i put inside

```
dataType: 'text',
mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined',
```

Any ideas? What would have been base64 compatible? Text is not as it seems
I think splitting the text might work.

Comment: Try [session upload progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

Comment: If i put inside my php code something like update session, the php will execute after the whole post is being done. I want it to execute before that.

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559264/possible-to-calculate-how-much-data-been-loaded-with-ajax) might help you. It uses xhr progress event.

Comment: [Another possibly useful post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol This is available only to XMLHttpRequest2 compatible browsers

Comment: @Xeijp this return 0.124 and 1 in a sec and then freezes.

Comment: @SpyrosSakellaropoulos True, but that's all modern browsers. If people are too lazy to update their browsers, do they deserve all the shininess of a beautiful web?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol After trying it it doesn't work , i think i may need to modify the dataurl to split it into pieces and chunk upload them.